# adjust height of bootstrap table based on tables returned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have pages with several tables being returned which can contain just a couple records. You can see the example on my site on [this page](http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/word-lists/words-with-q/) where the tables with 2 and three letter words only has a few records. The rest of the table is blank at the bottom till the full height of the table is reached. What I want is to adjust the table automatically based on the amount of records that are returned so there is no white space.

I display a max of 10 records per pagination so basically if there are less than 10 records returned it would need to adjust the height, otherwise it can have the full height which is `height: 538` which is the amount of pixels based on the height of 10 records.

I am using javascript table so here is my code

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript-2').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: '2.json',
    height: 538,
    cache: false,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    sortable: true,
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    columns: [{
        field: 'word',
        title: '2 Letter Words',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'score',
        title: 'Scrabble&reg; Points',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20',
        sortOrder: 'desc'
    }]
});

<table id="table-javascript-2"></table>
```

Is it possible to adjust the height of the table if there are less than 10 records?

Comment: Why do have to give the table a specific height in the first place? Just let it be dynamically and use paddings to get your desired height with 10 rows..

Comment: @Sebsemillia OMG It worked. I didn't even realize that simply removing the `height` attribute it does exactly what I want it to do...sometimes its the most simplest things that slip my mind. Make your comment an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. In general, you should only give specific height to elements when it is absolutely necessary. I created an answer as requested..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply remove the specific height of the table and let it be dynamic. Give each row a certain padding, so that you get your desired height with 10 rows and all should be good.